# How do I configure the firwall to open all ports to a certain zone?

Tags: linux, networking, firewall, kvm-switch

I created a virtual machine via qemu/kvm on my machine.

The NIC name of this virtual machine is virbr0, and it is managed by the libvirt area of the firewall:

```bsh
$ sudo firewall-cmd --zone=libvirt --list-all
libvirt (active)
  target: ACCEPT
  icmp-block-inversion: no
  interfaces: virbr0
  sources: 
  services: dhcp dhcpv6 dns ssh tftp
  ports: 
  protocols: icmp ipv6-icmp
  forward: no
  masquerade: no
  forward-ports: 
  source-ports: 
  icmp-blocks: 
  rich rules: 
        rule priority="32767" reject
```

Since there is no network security problem, I want to directly make the firewall open all host ports to the virtual machine.

what should I do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In fact, just add tcp and udp to protocols.

```
$ alias f-c-p="sudo firewall-cmd --permanent --zone=libvirt"
$ f-c-p --add-protocols tcp
$ f-c-p --add-protocols udp
$ sudo firewall-cmd --reload
```